# JSON query in a post request from Python and save result as csv file

Tags: python, json, csv, post, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a program that will connect to a specified url:

```
http://api.scb.se/OV0104/v1/doris/sv/ssd/START/BO/BO0104/BostadsbestandK
```

and use this query:

```
{ "query": [ { "code": "Region", "selection": { "filter": "vs:RegionRiket99", "values": [ "00" ] } }, { "code": "Hustyp", "selection": { "filter": "item", "values": [ "FLERBO", "SMÅHUS" ] } }, { "code": "Tid", "selection": { "filter": "item", "values": [ "2012" ] } } ], "response": { "format": "csv" } }
```

I would then like to store the result into a csv file.

This is the code I have so far:

```
import urllib.request
import json

url = 'http://api.scb.se/OV0104/v1/doris/sv/ssd/START/BO/BO0104/BostadsbestandK'

data = '{ "query": [ { "code": "Region", "selection": { "filter": "vs:RegionRiket99", "values": [ "00" ] } }, { "code": "Hustyp", "selection": { "filter": "item", "values": [ "FLERBO", "SMÅHUS" ] } }, { "code": "Tid", "selection": { "filter": "item", "values": [ "2012" ] } } ], "response": { "format": "csv" } }'
data = json.dumps(data)
```

Comment: No, I can't figure out how to use a "raw" json query, i.e. like it is defined by the API owner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should **not** define the query as a string; leave it a Python object:

```
data = { "query": [ { "code": "Region", "selection": { "filter": "vs:RegionRiket99", "values": [ "00" ] } }, { "code": "Hustyp", "selection": { "filter": "item", "values": [ "FLERBO", "SMÅHUS" ] } }, { "code": "Tid", "selection": { "filter": "item", "values": [ "2012" ] } } ], "response": { "format": "csv" } }
data = json.dumps(data)
```

You'll need to set a `application/json` request header to indicate what the contents are. You can do so with a `urllib.request.Request()` object; do encode the JSON data to UTF-8 first:

```
request = urllib.request.Request(url, data.encode('utf8'))
request.add_header('content-type', 'application/json')
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
```

Now you can save the CSV to a file; using [`shutil.copyfileobj()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) would make this efficient even for large responses:

```
import shutil

with open(csvfilename, 'wb') as outf:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response, outf)
```

Comment: I get this error message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Lagring\Python\PostRequest 1.py", line 17, in <module>
    shutil.copyfileobject(response, outf)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'copyfileobject'

Comment: @user3933746: my apologies, that was a typo on my side.